# Use Address tokens in view

Tags: views, commerce, tokens, entities

Within a view display, I am trying to display only the first name of a customer.  The information is collected via a standard [addressfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) form.  Within the available "Replacement Patterns" none of the tokens created in `addressfield.tokens.inc` are available.

This is the thread in which the functionality was added: https://www.drupal.org/node/1188778

The name of the field is `commerce_customer_shipping` - am I missing something by trying to use `[commerce_customer_shipping:first-name]`?

Thanks!

Comment: are you including the address field in the list of fields (even with a exclude from display)? ABOVE the field that is trying to access the token?

Comment: @Geoff, I'm trying to rewrite the address field. The field itself is available as a token [commerce_customer_shipping]